# Remove query string after rewrite old URLs with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

For my Dutch [website](http://watiseropderadio.nl) I want to redirect some old URLs to a new path.

I want to redirect URLs like this:

```
/playlist?artist=Bob+Marley    ->    /zoeken/Bob+Marley
/playlist?artist=Rammstein     ->    /zoeken/Rammstein
```

I'm come up with this to far:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^artist=(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^playlist        /zoeken/%1     [NC,L,R=301]
```

The only problem right now is that the query string keeps showing up in after the redirect:

```
http://watiseropderadio/zoeken/Bob+Marley?artist=Bob+Marley
```

How do I remove this query string?

Answer (score 2):

You need a `?` at the end:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^artist=(.*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^playlist        /zoeken/%1?     [NC,L,R=301]
# here --------------------------------^
```

By default, query strings are appended to the rule's target automatically unless you have a `?` to construct your own query string. With just a `?` at the end, you're constructing a blank query string and the existing query string won't get appended without the `QSA` flag.